# Copy/move all files which last modified date are in a given month

Tags: bash, date, copy, move

I have a question about terminal command. At work, we receive in a folder many files everyday. Today we decide to organize this full amount of files collecting them in folders using year and month as a rule.

Question, how can i move all the files which last modified date are in the range of the month of April of 2013, for example.

Comment: Your boss could as well hire a programmer for that!

Comment: What have you tried?  Barring that, what do you have access to?  Just bash? Ruby? We need a little more before we can really help.

Comment: I'm trying with bash command but doesn't work well.

Comment: what is the command you tried and doesn't work well ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily select files whose modification times are in a time range with the `find` command. Here's an example with gnu find, which makes this fairly simple:

```
find . -newermt 'Apr 1, 2013 00:00' -not -newermt 'May 1, 2013 00:00' \
       -exec mv -t /path/to/April_2013/directory '{}' '+'
```

`man find` for all the gory details.